# Enzyme - Mount can't find element by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I construct the wrapper:

```
this.wrapper = mount(<App />, { context: this.store });
```

Then I try to find a certain HTML element by its id:

```
console.log("WRAPPER:", this.wrapper.debug());
return this.wrapper.find('#Form-input[0]-fields-field1');
```

The wrapper is unable to find this element. The output of the console.log is as follows:

```
WRAPPER:
<Many children/components down...>
    <input name="Form-input[0].fields.field1" onBlur={[Function]} onChange={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="asdf" type="text" id="Form-input[0]-fields-field1" disabled={false} />
<Many more things after this...>
```

So the input with the correct id is definitely there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are using an ID selector `#Form-input[0]-fields-field1` but I believe that `[` and `]` are invalid for [CSS IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors), perhaps you could search for the input by name, does `input[name="Form-input[0]-fields-field1"]` work? And if I am wrong and the square brackets are in fact OK, you may still need to escape them in the query!

Comment: You are correct! However, it seems that wrapper.find doesn't allow for escaped characters. Thus, I ended up solving it by calling wrapper.find({ id: 'Form-input[0]-fields-field1' }) which worked fine.

Comment: Glad you fixed it! I checked Enzyme's repo for issues related to this - they are working on a solution to improve selectors.

Comment: Yeah the fact that the argument to `find` isn't treated like a normal css selector string is super confusing! It seems that it looks for the ] character, at which point it ignores everything else after that character.